# Charged Sphere Electric Potential

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential

I would like to know what's wrong with this calculation of the electric potential of a charged sphere. I've seen that my final result should have the opposite sign. I would like to know if there's something wrong with the $\bar{dl}$. I think that if the integral is going from $\infty$ to r the $\bar{dl}$ should point in the $-\hat{r}$ direction.

Thanks!

[image: Potential]

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind This is a conceptual question in that the OP does not understand how the integration works. So although it looks very much like a “check my work” question it is more than that. What I am pleased about is that it looks as though the OP now understands the idea behind setting up the integral and then the placement of the limits does the rest.

Comment: The question IS about a specific physics concept, the questioner HAS worked through the calculation and, as Farcher remarks in the first answer, the error is a common one and so the question IS therefore useful to the broader community.

Comment: @Farcher It's a textbook example of a check-my-work question. The question doesn't even explain *why* the asker thinks this calculation is wrong, let alone what the correct result is. It's possible that there is a rephrasing of this question, with a little bit more context besides a screenshot of a calculation, that would be on-topic, but as written it is a check-my-work question. If you think this question can be improved to fit our guidelines, please edit it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just edited the post. Feel free to change it if you wish. I appreciate both answers although I don't know who gave the -1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have made a very common error in that you have introduced a minus sign in the second line of your derivation because you have prejudged the direction in which the test charge is going to move.

The work done by the electric field is $\vec E \cdot d\vec l$.

Assume that $\vec E = E\, \hat r$ and $d\vec l = dr \,\hat r$ where $E$ and $dr$ are components of the electric field and the incremental displacement in the $\hat r$ direction.

So the work done by the electric field is $E \, \hat r \cdot dr\, \hat r = E\,dr$.

Note that no extra negative sign has been introduced as nothing has been stated about the actual direction of the electric field or the direction of motion of the test charge.
For the electric field you can assign a sign to $E$ dependent on whether the charge producing the field is positive or negative.
In your example you have stated that the field is positive because the charge is positive so $E = + \dfrac {Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$

Now what about the sign of $dr$?

The assignment of sign is made as part of the integration when you put in the limits of integration.
When you start at infinity and move to $r$ the increments in the $\hat r$ direction will come out to be negative as part of the integration process.
Remember that reversing the limits of an integration reverses the sign of the integral.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should have $(\hat{r)}$ rather than $(-\hat{r)}$ in your second line. The fact that you're going in the $(-\hat{r)}$ direction is taken account of by the limits on your integration.

Comment: It would be courteous of the negative voter to explain why (s)he gave that vote.